# DWR Incomplete reply from server

Tags: dwr

I am working on Dwr with Dojo, i am using DWR Version 3.0.RC2 dwr.jar (1.1Mb) jar file.
 Onpage load time giving alert error "Incomplete reply from server"

Comment: Find solution ? Upgrade dwr version  ?